# An error occurred because there is no graphics environment available

Tags: apache-flex, xlib

I am getting below error when I try to use hudson and maven, Any idea how to resolve?

```
Xlib: connection to ":1.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An error occurred because there is no graphics environment available.  Please set the headless-server setting in the Flex configuration file to true.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.InternalError: An error occurred because there is no graphics environment available.
```

Thanks
sharp

Comment: Any input? Any document to install Xlib?

Comment: Did you try following the suggestion given in the message about the "headless-server" setting?    Xlib must already be installed, since it's printing the error messages that start with "Xlib:".

Answer (score 3):

Under `<compiler>` tag in `flex-config.xml` add

```
<headless-server>true</headless-server>
```